# When i deploy my NodeJS app it doesn't access the database

Tags: javascript, node.js

My NodeJS app works just fine in my localhost, but when I deployed it to Heroku it takes forever and then some error come up.

when i query some data i get this error

> pesquisa:100          POST https://cadfi.herokuapp.com/getUsers 503 (Service Unavailable)
> VM88:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

my heroku site
https://cadfi.herokuapp.com/pesquisa

this is the code in my retrieve.ejs (page)

```js
        function sendData(e){
        if (e.value !== "total") {
            const searchResults = document.getElementById('searchResults');
            fetch('getUsers',{
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify({payload: e.value})
            }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
                let payload = data.payload;
                searchResults.innerHTML = '';
                if (payload.length < 1){
                    searchResults.innerHTML = '<p>Nome não encontrado</p>';
                    return;
                }
                payload.forEach((item,index)=>{
                    if (index <0) searchResults.innerHTML += '<hr>';
                    searchResults.innerHTML += `<p>${item.firstName} ${item.lastName} .. Total de dívidas R$ ${item.dividaUm+item.dividaDois}.</p>`;
                });
                    return;
            });
        } else {
            const searchResults = document.getElementById('searchResults');
            fetch('getTotalDivida',{
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify({payload: e.value})
            }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
                let payload = data.payload;
                searchResults.innerHTML = '';
                if (payload.length < 1){
                    searchResults.innerHTML = '<p>Nome não encontrado</p>';
                    return;
                }
                const total = payload.reduce((acc, obj) =>{
                    return acc + obj.dividaUm + obj.dividaDois
                },0);
                searchResults.innerHTML += `<p>Total de dívidas R$ ${total}.</p>`

            });
        }
    }
```

this is in my server

```js
app.post('/getUsers', async (req, res) =>{
    let payload = req.body.payload.trim();
    let search = await User.find({firstName: {$regex: new RegExp('^'+payload+'.*','i')}}).exec();
    //console.log(payload)

    //limitar resultados a 10
    search = search.slice(0,10);
    res.send({payload: search});
});
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Check the html contents of the response and check the server log.

Comment: Express ignores errors thrown in async handlers. Wrap your handler in `try catch` and print the error. I guess that the error is never handled so you never get any response.

Comment: Do you have a .env file to save database credentials if it is not pushed add it please in the config vars of setting in Heroku?